# Integral Criteria for Functions to be Zero Almost Everywhere

Tags: real-analysis, integration, lebesgue-integral

While reading the proof of Lemma 2 in the following link, I realized they only proved the case of a nonnegative function $f$, but that's not an hypothesis of the lemma. So, what happens if $f$ takes negative values? Does the lemma remain true? Is the proof similar to the nonnegative case?

> **Lemma 2:** Let $f$ is a Lebesgue integrable function on $[a, b]$ and let $F(x)=\int_a^x f(t) d t$.  If for all $x \in[a, b]$ we have that $F(x)=0$ then $f(x)=0$ almost everywhere on $[a, b]$

**Link of the proof:** http://mathonline.wikidot.com/integral-criteria-for-functions-to-be-zero-almost-everywhere

Comment: the lemma is true for any chosen Lebesgue integrable function not only for non-negative functions. The point is that the function defined by $F(x):=\int_{[a,x]}f\mathop{}\!d \lambda $ is differentiable a.e. and $F'(x)=f(x)$, therefore if $F=0$ it follows that $f=0$ a.e. Take a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_differentiation_theorem).

Comment: @Masacroso Do you think that the negative case can be concluded from the proof of the nonnegative case? Without using the differentiation tool.

Comment: Please type the mathematics in your posts, its not too hard

Comment: @CalvinKhor Thanks. You typed it with a mistake, but I already corrected it.

Comment: @Masacroso Yes, I did read the proof. They prove by contradiction that $m(S)=0$, where $S$ is the set where $f>0$. But my question is: what happens when $f<0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the proof of the Lemma 2 in the link it shows that $m(\{x\in[a,b]:f(x)>0\})=0$, therefore $f$ is non-positive almost everywhere. Then it follows from the Lemma 1 that $-f=0$ almost everywhere, so we conclude that $f=0$ a.e.

That is, if we set $S:=\{x\in[a,b]: f(x)>0\}$ then
$$
\int_{[a,b]}f\mathop{}\!d \lambda =\overbrace{\int_{S}f\mathop{}\!d \lambda}^{=0} +\int_{[a,b]\setminus S}f \mathop{}\!d \lambda =-\int_{[a,b]\setminus S}|f|\mathop{}\!d \lambda =0\\[2ex]
\therefore\quad \mathbf{1}_{[a,b]\setminus S}\,|f|=0\text{ a.e. }\implies \mathbf{1}_{[a,b]\setminus S}\,f=0\text{ a.e. }\implies f=0\text{ a.e. }
$$